# import services header in android project

Tags: android, compilation

If you look at the android source code, for importing header files

Path 1: /framework/base/core/java/...... subdirectories and header files

Path 2: /framework/base/services/java/com......subdirectories and header files

In my android project, when I start import android....., it follows path 1.
But I want to import header files from Path2.

May be there is a very easy way to do this but my ignorance with android is in way. Any ideas?
Is this something that can be addressed by adding a jar?

EDIT: it looks like android.jar does not have Path 2 included in it.. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get framework.jar from the device and put it in your project. It looks like you want to compile your project with hidden API.

> adb pull /system/framework/framework.jar

Here is the reference: http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-2-hacking-around/